# How to pattern match against Unicode characters by PostgreSQL `SIMILAR TO` expressions?

Tags: postgresql, unicode, pattern-matching

In a PostgreSQL database, I have a column named `metaid` of type `text` whose value contains digits as specified in [the third edition of XML 1.0 standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xml-20040204/#NT-Digit):

```
Digit ::= [#x0030-#x0039] | [#x0660-#x0669] | [#x06F0-#x06F9] | [#x0966-#x096F] | [#x09E6-#x09EF] | [#x0A66-#x0A6F] | [#x0AE6-#x0AEF] | [#x0B66-#x0B6F] | [#x0BE7-#x0BEF] | [#x0C66-#x0C6F] | [#x0CE6-#x0CEF] | [#x0D66-#x0D6F] | [#x0E50-#x0E59] | [#x0ED0-#x0ED9] | [#x0F20-#x0F29]
```

In the [documentation of PostgreSQL for `SIMILAR TO` expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-SIMILARTO-REGEXP), matching against such Unicode characters by their range is not mentioned.

I need to put a `CHECK` constraint on the column for ensuring the pattern of the entered value conforms to the required format.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a check constraint:

```
CHECK (col ~ '^[0-9\u0660-\u0669\u06F0-\u06F9\u0966-\u096F]+$')
```

The pattern starts with "beginning of string" (`^`) and ends with "end of string" (`$`)and allows one or more "digits" in between.

`^` and `$` are necessary, otherwise the pattern would match `abc123efg`.